# Flashing a Cyclone IV's SROM chip via its JTAG connection

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, flashing

Is there an inbuilt or pre-existing feature I can use to accomplish Flashing a Cyclone IV's(EP4CE6E22C8) SROM(W25Q16BV) chip via its JTAG connection?  Maybe some setting when compiling in Quartus to tell the FPGA "Hey flash this".  Or a specific command for OpenOCD.

I saw that there are IP cores to manually flash the device, but I really do not want to go down that rabbit hole.  Programming my own flasher sounds like an unnessisary hell at my experience level.

I hope this is good enough of a question, Ive been suffering with this for months, if you need any more information

---

### INFO:

I have a **W25Q16BV SROM** chip connected *directly*to a **EP4CE6E22C8** in AS config mode. (Data input on SROM has single direct connection to FPGA's ASDO)
And to that FPGA I have a JTAG connection that connects to my computer via a **J-Link** adapter.
Controlling the J-Link adapter is **OpenOCD** that uploades compiled data(SVF file) provided by **Quartus Prime**.
The board is from an obscure seller, but it did come pre-flashed with an example program that starts upon every reset, so there must be some way they uploaded this.